# 'Failed to login: Invalid ip' when connecting to servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to connect to a minecraft server, it says

> Failed to login: Invalid ip 123.123.123.*

Giving me my IP address with the last octet asterisked out.

---

Now the Minecraft launcher forgets my logged-in accounts, which is unusual.

---

Now I can't log into the launcher nor the website, Mojang tells me I have an invalid email or password.

Answer (score 15):

For stuff like this, I always head over to the [Mojang Portal](https://help.mojang.com/).  This way you know the information is authentic and current.

In this case, 18 minutes ago, in their twitter feed, they posted:

> We’re working on fixing the issue people are currently experiencing with authentication - TM