# How do I fix Invalid IP? Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It appears connecting on any premium account does not let me connect to any servers and displays:

> "Failed to login: Invalid ip 111.111.111.111"

Possibly Minecraft Authentication issue, from reports is seems it may be worldwide?
Login authentication through the launcher works fine. But connecting to a server responds with "Invalid ip"

**EDIT**
MojangStatus has posted on twitter regarding this for anyone wondering:

> We’re working on fixing the issue people are currently experiencing
>   with authentication - TM

https://twitter.com/MojangStatus/status/998920638709497856

I will also link the mojang portal although it says everything is working fine:
https://help.mojang.com/

This question provides far more useful info and the correct answer than: [How do I fix Invalid IP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/332697/how-do-i-fix-invalid-ip)
If the answers could be marked appropriately and not marked as a duplicate as this does not provide users with the correct answer. Thank you

Comment: Related: [How do I fix Invalid IP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/332697/30879)

Comment: If the correct answer below could be marked as answer that would be great as I cannot seem to mark this as answered. The post it is claiming has the answer does not. If this could be corrected that would be much appreciated.

Comment: If we edit information out of your question, the response is not to ignore it and re-add it. It has no bearing on your question whatsoever, so it doesn't belong. Answers don't belong in the question, regardless, so that has to go.

Comment: @tomtehtom You can also [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/), but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!

Comment: Frank the site told me to edit it, the answer is here and therefore the question is answered, having the site falsely point to a wrong answer on a different question is not how things should work :D I didn't realise it was edited out as it gave me no notification, I just assumed I hadn't click save and therefore re-added it. Apologies.

Comment: @Virusbomb thanks for that info, seems strange people don't want to mark the more useful question/answer as the answer and instead make it point to incorrect information :P Oh well. This issue is sorted. Thanks all

Answer (score -2):

It seems the issue has now been fixed by Mojang although no official post for a confirmed fix.

Restarting your Game & Launcher will clear your accounts and you may need to login again with your credentials. After doing this you should be able to connect as normal.

**EDIT**
Mojang has confirmed the fix in a tweet:
https://twitter.com/MojangStatus/status/998935258165927941

> We’ve deployed a fix for the authentication issues people were having, service should now be resumed - TM

Comment: You listed the same information in your question.  I do not think this provides an answer to your question either, but more information about the issue instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying? This provides what I think is the answer to my question. Posting it as an answer makes more sense that putting the answer in the question surely?

Comment: Now that you've edited the post, it is a potential answer.  Before that, it was just information about the problem, but it didn't tell you how to fix the problem.

Comment: Alright then, if this could be marked as the answer as it appears I cannot mark it that would be great. Apologies Timmy Jim, seems your comment came up way after I edited it so I assume it was commented on my edit, not the previous. Thanks again.

Comment: @tomtehtom you are the only one who can mark an answer as the "correct" one as it is your question. It does make you wait some time to do so but you should be able to select the checkmark yourself.